# Afterburner.fx injection into non-presenter classes possible?

Tags: java, javafx, dependency-injection

As the title goes, is it possible to inject objects into non-presenter/controller classes with afterburner.fx? Been trying to get it working but frankly making no progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, using the Afterburner framework injection works in presenter classes:

```
public class AfterburnerPresenter {

    @Inject
    private Model model;

}
```

but it doesn't work in non-presenter classes:

```
public class JavaFXApplication100 extends Application {

    @Inject
    private Model model;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        model.set...;
    }

}
```

this will return a null pointer exception, as the `model` is null.

The reason for this can be found [here](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/airhacks/afterburner/injection/Injector.java#L55): when the presenter is instantiated, the fields annotated with `Inject` will be injected.

This only works for presenters, and no other classes are scanned looking for `@Inject`.

Fortunately, there is a way to inject model, service or even presenter classes into non-presenter classes. If we check again the afterburner.fx `Injector` [class](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/airhacks/afterburner/injection/Injector.java), we'll find some static methods that will help us with that. Basically:

- `Injector.instantiatePresenter(Class<T> clazz)`,
- `Injector.instantiateModelOrService(Class<T> clazz)`.

**Sample**

Let's create a quick sample.

*Model*

```
public class Model {

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final String getText() { return text.get(); }
    public final void setText(String value) { text.set(value); }
    public final StringProperty textProperty() { return text; }

}
```

*AfterburnerPresenter*

```
public class AfterburnerPresenter {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Inject
    private Model model;

    public void initialize() {
        label.textProperty().bind(model.textProperty());
    }    

}
```

*AfterburnerView*

```
public class AfterburnerView extends FXMLView {

}
```

*afterburner.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="<your.package>.AfterburnerPresenter">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="89.0" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

*Application class*

Let's now inject the model into the main class:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = new AfterburnerView().getView();

    Model model = Injector.instantiateModelOrService(Model.class);
    model.setText("This is a test");

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

If you run it:

[image: inject model]

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation for my very short question :) Just what I needed it's working perfectly thank you.

Comment: Spoke a little too soon. While this is working wonderfully to share my Model class, what about sharing multiple instances of a class? For example injecting several different Pane objects into a non-presenter class?

Comment: Once you inject an object, its reference is added to an internal map, so you can't create different instances of it. Basically it is a singleton. About injecting UI objects in non-presenter classes, I don't think that's a good idea if those are not UI related. You should respect the MVC after all. But if you have for instance a factory cell implementation, it could make sense. Anyway, note that if you have an object defined by its view/presenter/fxml, you can create as many instances as you want from it with `new ObjectView().newView()`.